# Вопрос по изменению данных в Stream API

Tags: java

[image]
Имеем на выходе из потока Map [Имя студента, средняя оценка] можно ли как то в потоке изменить все значения в зависимости от среднего балла студента, например если > 4.5 то меняем на "Good" если > 4 && < 4.5 на "Normal" и тд, ну и на выходе получить соответственно уже Map [String, String]

Comment: Вставляйте код текстом, чтобы его можно было скопировать.

Comment: Ну map же......

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы можете сделать это прямо в лямбда функции, просто добавив нужные условия после получения средней оценки.

```
student -> { 
   double average = student.getMarks(). ... .orElse(0.0);
   
   if (average < 2) return "Bad";
   else if (average >= 2 && average < 4) return "Normal";
   else return "Good";
}
```

Или лучше оформить это функцией, к примеру `private String getStringMark(double mark) { ... }` и передавать ей значения.

```
student -> getStringMark(student.getMarks(). ... .orElse(0.0))
```

Comment: Спасибо, но отдельным методом или через if/else я знал как сделать, задание внести изменения непосредственно в текущем потоке (

Comment: @Linux, ну формально обработчик внутри потока как раз, а не где-то вне него. Вы все равно упретесь в необходимость написать функцию обработки логики, где бы она ни находилась. Других методов StreamAPI не предусматривает. Поэтому мне не совсем тогда понятно, что вы хотите найти.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Map<String,List<St>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(el ->{
            if(el.grades.stream().mapToInt(q->q).average().getAsDouble() > 5){
                return "Good";

            }
            if(el.grades.stream().mapToInt(q->q).average().getAsDouble() < 5){
                return "Bad";

            }
            else {
                return "Middle";
            }

        }));
```